# While data is fetched add link with href to ID

Tags: hyperlink, makefile

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM something ORDER by date_sent DESC") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 

Print "<table width='1200px' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
Print "<tr id='data'>";
Print "<div  class='border'>";
Print "<td width='80px'><div align='center'>".$info['case_number'] ."</div></td>";
Print "<td width='80px'><div align='center'>".$info['credit_number'] . "</div></td>";
Print "</tr>";
Print "</table>";
} 
?>
```

I want to make case_number link to ID

```
I made: <td width='80px'><div align='center'> <a href='edit.php?id=".$info['id'] ."'>      ".$info['case_number'] ." </a> </div></td>";
```

but it do not work.

Can you explain how can I make this work? Thank you

Comment: What error you are getting in this?

Comment: It don't work but i found solution:
<a href='update.php?id=$info[id]'>".$info['case_number'] ."</a>